# Adding columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with some housing data in python. I am trying to calculate price in sq feet and add it to the dataframe. I am able to do the calculation alone, but when I try to add the column back to the dataframe, I keep receiving an error.

Code:

```
 price_feet=[data['price']/data['sqft_living']]
```

This works on it own

This does not

```
 data['price_feet']=[data['price']/data['sqft_living']]
```

Error received:
Length of values does not match length of index

I assume that there is not a match in the data with the two variables. This is why I am able to do the calculation but not add it back to the dataframe. I have tried looking up some answers but apparently haven't found the right fix yet.

Thanks!

Comment: the answer is right in the error message . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the brackets:

```
data['price_feet']=data['price']/data['sqft_living']
```

The square brackets were returning a list where the first item was a series. You just want the series.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html)

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'price': [1000, 2000], 'sqft_living': [100, 250]})
data['price_feet'] = data.price.div(data.sqft_living)

>>> data
   price  sqft_living  price_feet
0   1000          100          10
1   2000          250           8
```

> Signature: data.price.div(other, level=None, fill_value=None, axis=0)
>   Docstring:
>   Floating division of series and other, element-wise (binary operator `truediv`).
>
> Equivalent to `series / other`, but with support to substitute a fill_value for
>   missing data in one of the inputs.